# Svelte: make component reactive to variable (rerender)

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I want to rerender "Body" (my svelte component) whenever "view.current" changes so it renders the corresponding .svelte view/component:

**App.svelte**

```
    <script>
    import Header from "./components/Header.svelte";
    import Footer from "./components/Footer.svelte";
    import Body from "./components/Body.svelte";

    import Login from "./views/Login.svelte";
    import Dashboard from "./views/Dashboard.svelte";

    import { view } from "./store";
</script>

<Header />
    <Body>
        {#if view.current === view.login}
            <Login />
        {:else if view.current === view.dashboard}
            <Dashboard />
        {/if}
    </Body>
<Footer />
```

In "Body.svelte" i just have a slot that gets styled

**Body.svelte**

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .container {
        padding: 1em;
        display: flex;
    }
    .content {
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
```

In Login.svelte (and other svelte components) i want to change "view.current":

**Login.svelte**

```
<script>
    import { view } from "../store";

    function handleLoginClick() {
        view.current = view.dashboard;
    }
</script>


<button type="button" on:click={handleLoginClick} class="btn btn-primary btn-lg login-btn">Login</button>

<style>
    .login-btn {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
```

**store.js**

```
    const user = {
    username: "",
    fullname: "",
    role: null,
    isLoggedIn: false
};

const view = {
    login: 1,
    dashboard: 2,
    current: 1
};

export {
    user,
    view
}
```

The value of "view.current" changes as expected, however "Body" does not update/rerender. So it always shows the login.svelte no matter to what "view.current" has been set.
Is there a quick and easy way to make "Body" reactive to "view.current" so that it rerenders so that the if/else-block in "App.svelte" get's reevaluated?

Comment: Why do you want your `Body` component to re-render?

Comment: When view.current is set to lets say "login" i want to render the stuff in login.svelte, when it is set to "dashboard" i want to render "dashboard.svelte" and so on.

Comment: is this `view` a svelte store ?

Comment: No, it's just a js file. I also tried to make "view" to a svelte.store, but it behaves the same way.
I have edited the post and added the contents of store.js.

Comment: Try `$: currentView = view.current;` and use `currentView` in the markup? Note: I might be completely wrong, I'm not yet 100% comfortable with Svelte.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work - same behavior. :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Importing a regular variable like that in a component creates a local copy of said variable. The `view` you are referring to in the Login is not shared with the one in App, so the changes are not reflected there.

The "Svelte-way" of sharing state like that accross components is to use a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store).

In your setup that would mean you define view as a store first:

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

const view = writable({
    login: 1,
    dashboard: 2,
    current: 1
});
```

In the components themselves you have to prefix the store with `$`

```html
<script>
    function handleLoginClick() {
        $view.current = $view.dashboard;
    }
</script>
```

```html
{#if $view.current === $view.login}
    <Login />
{:else if $view.current === $view.dashboard}
    <Dashboard />
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick. Did not know it creates a local copy of it.